# Linear order and well-order

Tags: logic, order-theory

The question is:
A linear(or total) order (L,=<) is a well-order if and only if (1) for every infinite decreasing sequence

x<sub>0</sub> =< x<sub>1</sub> =< x<sub>2</sub> =< ...

in L, there is an n such that for all m>n, x<sub>n</sub> =x<sub>m</sub>.

My answer (sketch) so far:

Assume the linear order (L, =<) and (1).

For every infinite sequence, we have (1). This gives us an x<sub>n</sub> ( with n the smallest number such that for every m>n, x<sub>n</sub> =x<sub>m</sub>.)* for every infinite sequence. These 'x<sub>n</sub>' will give us another infinite sequence, and with (1) will give us an element x<sub>n</sub> (with n again the smallest like before) such that for every x in L: x<sub>n</sub> =< x .

*= I got the hint that I had to use the axiom of choice, but I dont think I need it when I can just pick the smallest n for which this is true?

Comment: @Jay: Tags should describe what the question is about, not what it contains. Just because the axiom of choice is used somewhere does not merit the tag's use. If it were, the tag should have been used a lot more. This tag is reserved for questions which specifically ask about the role of the axiom (or a related principle)  in the proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the axiom of choice in order to prove that well-ordered are exactly those linear ordered without infinite decreasing sequences.

The reason is that it is consistent to have linearly ordered sets, which are not well-ordered, that have no countably infinite subsets. In fact it is even consistent that such set is a subset of the real numbers.

Your proof seems somewhat unclear to me. If $(L,\leq)$ is a linear order without an infinite decreasing sequence, take $A\subseteq L$ which is non-empty. Pick some $a_0\in A$, if it is was minimal, you are done. Otherwise there is some $a_1\in A$ such that $a_1<a_0$. Continue by induction and define a sequence $a_n$, and show that it is strictly decreasing, which is a contradiction to the assumption that no such sequence exists.

We use the axiom of choice in order to generate the sequence. By induction we only chose one next element, but the axiom of choice assures us that we can make all these choices uniformly and put them into one sequence.

Comment: Ah, so let me get this (and hopefully I will be repeating what you said):

You create a decreasing infinite sequence by picking an element a out of L. 
If a is the smallest, we are done. If not, there is at least one element that is smaller than a. 
To choose between those elements, we need the axiom of choice.
We can keep going on, but (1) will ensure that we will get a smallest element. Then we are done.

Is that ok?

Comment: Ryan, I am looking for a minimal element of $A$. If I find one, then I stop. But if I didn't find one, then the axiom of choice assures that the choices I made can be coherently put into a sequence which contradicts $(1)$.

Comment: It seems like I have to review the axiom of choice, because I understand the proof, but not why the axiom is necessary.

Comment: @Ryan: We can define arbitrarily long sequences by induction, but those are only finite sequences. We need some sort of "glue" to ensure that we can pass from finite sequences of every length to an infinite sequence. This is where the axiom of choice comes in. I think that this is probably one of the more delicate uses of the axiom of choice that I know of (this particular proof).

Comment: With some practice, we can recognize that we used AC, in this case a weak version of AC. Recognizing that it is *necessary* is far harder. We need to prove an independence result, or, more frequently, reduce the problem to someone else's independence result. To do this, we need a thorough knowledge of the various models of ZF that have unusual properties.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Why can you only get finite sequences with induction? The axiom of induction states that we can prove things for all n in N with the usual conditions. Thus, in this example, whenever we have a sequence of n decreasing elements, we can find another, smaller element. With induction this gives a sequence of infinite (as in N) elements. 

And: We are creating a sequence of decreasing elements. But (1) will ensure us that this sequence is finite! So why would we need the AC?

Comment: @Ryan: The axiom of induction is for the natural numbers which can be well-ordered to begin with. For general infinite sets you don't necessarily have that, and you need to have a choice function on *some* family of subsets in order to proceed. There is a model, which I mentioned in my answer, where there is a set of real numbers that have no infinite decreasing sequence, but every decreasing sequence can be extended by one more element.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think I get it now, thanks for your help! 

This is more explicit: We can find finite sequences of decreasing sequences. Now let A be the set of those decreasing sequences ((x1),(x1,x2),..) and let B the set A with an added element # not in A. Then define f: A -> B with f(x1)=#, f(x1,..,xn+1)=(x1,..,xn). This function is surjective, thus AC gives us a function s:B->A with f(s(b))=b.

Now we can define our sequence, which is a function from N to L, as followed: g(0)=s(#), g(n+1)=s(g(0),..,g(n)).
This function is well defined and gives us the infinite seq. we need for the contr.

Comment: @Ryan, close, but not quite there (at least in the form you have summed the argument into here). Fix $f$ to be a choice function on subsets of $A$ (it is enough to have $f$ choosing from initial segments of the order restricted to $A$). Now define by recursion $F(0)=a$ some $a\in A$; and $F(n+1)=f(\{x\in A\mid x<F(n)\})$ if $F(n)$ is not minimal; and $F(n+1)=F(n)$ if it is minimal. From $(1)$ we know that $a_n=F(n)$ is a decreasing sequence and must therefore stabilize, so we must have found a minimal element, otherwise the sequence would be strictly decreasing in contradiction to $(1)$.